# Is there a replacement of com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory in Java 9?

Tags: dns, jndi, java-9

The follow simple code:

```
Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable();
env.put( "java.naming.factory.initial", "com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory" );
DirContext dns = new InitialDirContext( env );
```

produce the follow exception in Java 9. Currently I use 9-ea+164-jigsaw-nightly.

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class:
com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessException:
class javax.naming.spi.NamingManager (in module java.naming) cannot access
class com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory (in module jdk.naming.dns) because module jdk.naming.dns
does not export com.sun.jndi.dns to module java.naming]
    at java.naming/javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:719)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:305)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:236)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:208)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.<init>(InitialDirContext.java:101)
```

Comment: related bug https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8153156

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked jdk-9+168 and I don't see this issue. Are you seeing it with a recent build?

Comment: I have try 9-ea+169 and it work now. Seems to be fixed.